# Does running single Wifi radio yield better coverage (2.4GHz vs 2.4/5GHz)?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a TP-Link AC1750 v2 router with DD-WRT on it. The room on the other side of the wall had OK reception till about half of the room, and after that was problematic.

I have switched off the 5GHz radio because I was trying to see if another device (Ubiquity NanoStation AC Loco 5GHz) could blast through the wall better. It didn't, but I noticed that now the 2.4GHz from the router has way better reception in the other room.

I'd like to understand what's happening here. Was the weaker signal due to some internal interference, or the router not having enough horsepower to maintain both signals adequately (it's around 6 years old)?

Comment: I very much doubt anything changed about 2.4 GHz. It’s just that signals at 5 GHz, being at a higher frequency, have less range and are more easily affected by obstacles.